# Is it possible to like/share Facebook posts that are displayed in website's Facebook feed?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

I am trying to add like/share functionality to Facebook feed posts that are displayed on my website.

In the current setup, I generate and cache a Facebook feed using PHP (FQL) which gives me access to all of the data under these tags: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/.

So the question is, how do I craft like/share buttons to directly like/share posts that are on Facebook? Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: You're already at the right place for [Facebook's api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/) ?

Comment: Yes, but that seems to be for sharing website content and not Facebook based stories. As I can't see any documentation regarding like/share of internal Facebook content.